# Chrome extension, on button click, jquery code to grab html of an active tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I'm writing my first chrome extension. It turns out it's not as simple as one would of hoped.

What I'm trying to do is this, when I click my extension button, jquery code grabs html of an active tab.

Please help me as my code wont work:(

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "First time",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a 'browser action' with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js" :["jquery.min.js", "popup.js"]
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },

  "permissions": ["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

**Popup.js**

```
 function getBgColors(tag){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert($("heaed").html());

        });
    }
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getBgColors);
```

Comment: I wonder who is the troll to down vote my post?

Comment: Well, count at least me, for calling [downvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) trolling.
Do read [introductory documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) more thoroughly; especially the part on [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).
Your question, as-is, is not useful to keep on Stack Overflow. It should be answered by reading those two docs pages; if you still have questions, read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try again.

Comment: Xan you answer is as good as 'You can just google and find your solution' or 'Read a book A or B'.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer. But: I pointed to the exact sources that are not book-sized.

Comment: downvoting question because of how the title was formated is misleading. the problem i have is well described and might be encountered by other pepople. Not everyone is a 'stackoverflow nerd' on here. Itd be cool if there was a better way for nerds to submit their recommndations/edits on titles or anything else that bothers you.

Comment: fair enough learning about stack everyday:)

Comment: Let me explain why this question is (objectively) bad. Title: not in the least helpful or interesting - result, no answers. The only way people choose questions to look at is by tag/title. Question, as it stands now: "Please help me as my code wont work:(" Any errors? You would get a helpful error message if you opened the JavaScript console. **It's critical you try to debug yourself!** To your credit, there is enough information to diagnose the problem, but this kind of problem is basic misunderstanding of the architecture solvable by reading the docs I linked.

Answer (score -1):

you should add a background page or event page, and register the event listener there.

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getBgColors);`

Comment: And that would achieve?.. `getBgColors` from the content script cannot be simply called from background. Messaging is needed.

Comment: to invoke actions in contentscript, you should use message passing, you can get after reading the devguide.